# How can I get a tinted highlight without tinting the entire piece?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, light

I want to give my highlights a little more color, such as in this image:

[image]

But using an environment map gives me pretty flat colors:

[image]

Is there a way to get this greater hue range, especially if I can get it just on a single object?

I tried adding a second light, but it really doesn't look good with environment lighting.

I also tried it without the environment, but any colored light tints everything that color, which I don't want. I want the shadows to be unaffected.

Compositor is fine too.

Edit this works, but the screen step seems too yellow:

[image]

Comment: I used what you gave :) If you have a problem to tweak nodes, post your blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com  with all textures that cause the yellowish result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can check Color Management, by default its set to Filmic that has a flat look (but for a good reason). You can switch to Standard, but probably better is to add a few nodes in Compositor - like Glare node.

[image]

Yeah ... separate effect for gem you can use ID mask of object or newly Cryptomatte feature.

[image]

Comment: this looks good, but my screen step adds a ton of yellow, and even if I turn it down, the brightest part is still yellowish (it should stay white)